# Can 2 observers isolated from each other measure a virtual particle and get different results?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Given 2 observers isolated from each other and a virtual particle (electron?) is measured for "Spin" by Observer 1 --- condensing it into reality with a state of "Up".

Observer 2 makes measurement of what they still perceive as a virtual particle with an unknown 50/50 chance of "Up" or "Down".

Could Observer 2 get different result for the Spin state?

Comment: Virtual particles are just a mathematical tool used in calculating things in quantum field theory - not an object that exists and whose properties can be measured. Most importantly, there's no way to measure their spin. I think your question can stand if you just make your electron real rather than "a virtual particle."

Comment: One a more general note, "a measurement" in quantum mechanics is the transfer of quanta of energy from the quantum system to the measurement system. Energy can only be transferred once (it's a locally conserved property), hence it is impossible to perform two measurements on the same quantum. There is an unfortunate tendency in the literature and public discussion to rename "quanta" as "particles", which leads to these kinds of misconceptions about what can and can not be done in quantum mechanics. What you are suggesting can't be done.

Comment: By "measure", I mean "collapse the wave function to see a real particle"

Comment: And that is one answer to my question ". Energy can only be transferred once (it's a locally conserved property), hence it is impossible to perform two measurements on the same quantum."

There is a controversy though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a variant on the 'Wigner's Friend' thought experiment. Wigner's friend has a lab inside an isolated box. He measures a particle's state, which has been prepared so it could be 50:50 'up' or 'down', and he observes 'up'. Wigner outside the box does not know what his friend observed; there is no interaction between them. As far as Wigner is concerned, no measurement has been made. The question is whether before Wigner opens the box, the particle and his friend are in a state of superposition, or whether his friend's observation has already collapsed the state.

Different interpretations of quantum mechanics disagree. Collapse interpretations (most of them) would mostly say that Wigner's friend collapses the wavefunction to a pure 'up' state, and any subsequent observation will give the same answer. The Everett interpretation (usually known as the Many Worlds Interpretation) says wavefunctions never collapse. So Wigner's friend *is* in a superposition of an observer seeing 'up' and an observer seeing 'down', and when Wigner opens the box, Wigner enters a superposition of seeing 'up' and seeing 'down' too.

In this latter case, it could be said that there is a version of Wigner's friend who sees 'up', and simultaneously a version of Wigner seeing 'down', which would seem to meet your requirements. However, the two states are orthogonal to one another, and cannot interact or perceive the other. When Wigner compares notes with his friend, they will always agree - either both see 'up' or both see 'down', never a mixture. The alternate history is unobservable. So nobody can be certain whether or not it happened.

There is no experimental way to decide which interpretation is correct - they make the same predictions about what will be observed, they differ only on what is unobservable. There is no definitive answer to your question - it depends on which interpretation of quantum 'collapse' you subscribe to. Reasons to pick one might be which is the simplest, most mathematically elegant, parsimonious, intuitive, or easy to calculate with. It's up to you.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this could mean that Wigner should make sure his friend is not around when the measurements are taken.

Could the test be administered in a double-slit experiment when the observers are unaware of the other? Would they see the same interference? I imagine "Yes"